# Sequelize: Bulk Create Return Object

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to get back all the objects that were saved using the `bulkCreate` command.

I beleive the commond is:

```
 User.bulkCreate(values, {returning: true})
```

or

```
 User.bulkCreate(values, { individualHooks: true })
```

**Which one is appropriate to use and where do I place this line?**

My model looks like this:

```
var User = sequelize.define("Users", {
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: 1
        },
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        }
    }, {
            tableName: 'Users',
            classMethods: {
                associate: function (models) {
                    User.belongsTo(models.Group, {
                        foreignKey: {
                            name: 'user_id',
                            allowedNull: false,

                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            hooks: {

            }
        });

return User;
```

Comment: I suppose put it at the end. About bulkCreate is a CRUD, i guess you have to put your columns fields there, is a scope of your table fields.

Comment: Thanks.  I tired putting it right before returning; however, I get the following error `ReferenceError: values is not defined`

Comment: can you gave us the schema table?

Comment: how do I do that?  Sorry new to javascript/node.

Comment: your table mysql  fields need to be the same as your fields object in the bulk to take your schema mysql use phpmyadmin or a tool as Toad if i understand. You can show just the structure of the table Users

Comment: what are you tryng to do exactly? bulkCreate method can be used to create multiple rows in a single query. passing to this method "returning: true" is useful to return all the rows just created. There is no point to call it in the model definition file.

Comment: That's exactly what I need to do.  Return the rows that I just created along with ID.

Comment: "returning: true" - Append RETURNING * to get back auto generated values (Postgres only)

[see sequelize references bulkCreate](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate) To obtain Instances for the newly created values, you will need to query for them again.

Comment: That's what I also concluded.  If you'd like to post an answer, I can accept it.